# Django docker migrations not working after renaming model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, amazon-rds

I have a Django Docker setup using postgresql in RDS.

I managed to run the project successfully once and edited some model names. After that I built and launched a new container.

I noticed that instead of getting the typical:
"We have detected changes in your database. Did you renamed XXX to YYY?"

I got all my models migrating for the first time and everything seemed to work until I got to the Django admin.

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/upload/earnings/
relation "upload_earnings" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "upload_earnings"
```

This is my Dockerfile.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    build: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - web
  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
  acme:
```

So to reproduce I first created the container.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
docker exec -it container_id sh
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
-Created Model1
-Created XXXX
```

then
I changed the model names.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
docker exec -it container_id sh
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
-Created Model1
-Created ZZZ
```

Comment: A migration creating that table has not been run (or doesn't exist). I see no indication that anything would run `migrate` here.

Comment: @AKX I'm executing the migrate command manually going inside the container with docker exec.

Comment: Okay. Well, in any case there is no `upload_earnings` table; check your existing migrations to see if there is a migration that would create it. If not, `makemigrations` so there is...

Comment: @AKX makemigrations says there are no existing migrations to apply.

Comment: Pretty sure `makemigrations` does not say that, since it's not a script that applies migrations...

Comment: @AKX The equivalent, no changes detected. It works the first time however the error is still on the admin panel. Also shouldn't it ask if I renamed the model or made changes instead of just migrating on the first go?

Comment: How many migration files for the `upload` app do you have all in all? What's in them?

Comment: @AKX Only 1. It has references to the new renamed model as CreateModel

Comment: Did you clear your database (or roll back the earlier version of that single migration) before re-migrating? Otherwise it's pretty clear: Django thinks the migration has been run, but the contents of the migration have changed, so your database and what Django thinks should be there are out of sync.

Comment: I agree that is the issue I just don't know what is the best approach? I think I'm going to need to make some changes to my Dockerfile to keep the migrations on sync after building new containers / pull from git. I sent you a request on codementor if you can give suggestions

Comment: I don't have the time for a full mentoring session right now, but: (1) Migrations belong in source control; you should never need to `makemigrations` anywhere but on your development machine. (2) Once you have a production database, don't modify existing migrations (unless you know exactly that the modification is safe; renaming things isn't). Instead, just make new migrations. (3) Right now, if your prod database doesn't contain anything of importance, clear it and start anew. If there is something important, you could try to manually rename the table to `upload_earnings`.

Comment: @AKX you seem to provide  bunch of invalid technical advice